# Synchronize & schedule facebook, google+, linked in status updates

Tags: facebook, desktop-client, social-networks, google+

I'm looking for a package that I can use to manage social media.

Ideal characteristics:

1. NOT software as a service.  Too many of these companies have either gone under, or have radically changed their terms of service.  I want an application/script that I can run on my own hardware, and pay for just once.  The application can run under linux, mac mountain lion or windows XP
2. Able to post on a schedule.
3. Able to take an existing post on one network, and copy it to one or more other networks. E.g. if I use the iPhone FB app to post a pic and comment on my personal page, I want that evening to propagate that post to other social networks.Ii
4. Able to post to personal and company page on Facebook.
5. Able to post to group on Facebook, and on linked-in.
6. Able to post or to delete a post at a scheduled time.
7. Able to post with pictures.